# Speed up string matching in emacs

Tags: optimization, elisp

I want to implement the [vim commandT plugin](https://wincent.com/products/command-t) in emacs. This code is mostly a translation from the [matcher](https://github.com/wincent/Command-T/blob/master/ruby/command-t/match.c).

I've got some elisp here that's still too slow to use on my netbook -
how can I speed it up?

```
(eval-when-compile (require 'cl))
(defun commandT-fuzzy-match (choices search-string)
  (sort (loop for choice in choices
              for score = (commandT-fuzzy-score choice search-string (commandT-max-score-per-char choice search-string))
              if (> score 0.0) collect (list score choice))
        #'(lambda (a b) (> (first a) (first b)))
        ))

(defun* commandT-fuzzy-score (choice search-string &optional (score-per-char (commandT-max-score-per-char choice search-string)) (choice-pointer 0) (last-found nil))
  (condition-case error
      (loop for search-char across search-string
            sum (loop until (char-equal search-char (elt choice choice-pointer))
                      do (incf choice-pointer)
                      finally return (let ((factor (cond (last-found (* 0.75 (/ 1.0 (- choice-pointer last-found))))
                                                         (t 1.0))))
                                       (setq last-found choice-pointer)
                                       (max (commandT-fuzzy-score choice search-string score-per-char (1+ choice-pointer) last-found)
                                            (* factor score-per-char)))))
    (args-out-of-range 0.0)   ; end of string hit without match found.
    ))

(defun commandT-max-score-per-char (choice search-string)
  (/ (+ (/ 1.0 (length choice)) (/ 1.0 (length search-string))) 2))
```

Be sure to compile that part, as that already helps a lot.
And a benchmark:

```
(let ((choices (split-string (shell-command-to-string "curl http://sprunge.us/FcEL") "\n")))
  (benchmark-run-compiled 10
      (commandT-fuzzy-match choices "az")))
```

Comment: Some explanation of what that code is supposed to do, or some comments would be helpful.

Comment: Sounds roughly like something `iswitchb` and/or `ido` offer. I would not be too surprised if Textmate got it from Emacs ... http://emacswiki.org/emacs/IswitchBuffers

Comment: [Here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Fuzzy_Completion) is a description of various kinds of fuzzy matching in Emacs Lisp, with references to the implementing code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some micro optimizations you can try:

- Use `car-less-than-car` instead of your lambda expression.  This has no visible effect since the time is not spent in `sort` but in `commandT-fuzzy-score`.
- Use `defun` instead of `defun*`: those optional arguments with a non-nil default have a non-negligible hidden cost.  This reduces the GC cost by almost half (and you started with more than 10% of the time spent in the GC).
- (* 0.75 (/ 1.0 XXX)) is equal to (/ 0.75 XXX).
- use `eq` instead of `char-equal` (that changes the behavior to always be case-sensitive, tho).  This makes a fairly large difference.
- use `aref` instead of `elt`.
- I don't understand why you pass `last-found` in your recursive call, so I obviously don't fully understand what your algorithm is doing.  But assuming that was an error, you can turn it into a local variable instead of passing it as an argument.  This saves you time.
- I don't understand why you make a recursive call for every `search-char` that you find, instead of only for the first one.  Another way to look at this is that your `max` compares a "single-char score" with a "whole search-string score" which seems rather odd.  If you change your code to do the `max` outside of the two `loop`s with the recursive call on `(1+ first-found)`, that speeds it up by a factor of 4 in my test case.
- The multiplication by `score-per-char` can be moved outside of the loop (this doesn't seem to be true for your original algorithm).

Also, the Elisp as implemented in Emacs is pretty slow, so you're often better off using "big primitives" so as to spend less time interpreting Elisp (byte-)code and more time running C code.  Here is for example an alternative implementation (not of your original algorithm but of the one I got after moving the `max` outside of the loops), using regexp pattern maching to do the inner loop:

```
(defun commandT-fuzzy-match-re (choices search-string)
  (let ((search-re (regexp-quote (substring search-string 0 1)))
        (i 1))
    (while (< i (length search-string))
      (setq search-re (concat search-re
                              (let ((c (aref search-string i)))
                                (format "[^%c]*\\(%s\\)"
                                        c (regexp-quote (string c))))))
      (setq i (1+ i)))

    (sort
     (delq nil
           (mapcar (lambda (choice)
                     (let ((start 0)
                           (best 0.0))
                       (while (string-match search-re choice start)
                         (let ((last-found (match-beginning 0)))
                           (setq start (1+ last-found))
                           (let ((score 1.0)
                                 (i 1)
                                 (choice-pointer nil))
                             (while (setq choice-pointer (match-beginning i))
                               (setq i (1+ i))
                               (setq score (+ score (/ 0.75 (- choice-pointer last-found))))
                               (setq last-found choice-pointer))
                             (setq best (max best score)))))
                       (when (> best 0.0)
                         (list (* (commandT-max-score-per-char
                                   choice search-string)
                                  best)
                               choice))))
                   choices))
     #'car-less-than-car)))
```

Comment: The `last-found` is used to calculate the distance to the previous match found - the longer the distance between two matches, the smaller the score.

Comment: Actually, the way you use it, it's the distance to the previously-found *character* rather than the previous match (since you recurse before finishing the match).  This said, I don't understand why you'd care about the distance to the previous match.

Comment: Because the [reference implementation](https://github.com/wincent/Command-T/blob/master/ruby/command-t/match.c#L97-99) does.

Comment: The basic idea is that when I type `org`, the file `random.org` should be rated higher than `foobarbazbuarg`.

Comment: No, the reference implementation does it differently: you recurse with the whole `search-string`, whereas the reference's recursion passes the `i` argument, so the recursion only matches "the rest of the search string", which makes a lot more sense.